# OS X Virtualization on Linux?

Tags: virtualization

HI All,

What are my options if I want to Virtualize OS X Server, but my host OS is Linux?

I have a new i7 System and I might sell my Mac Pro

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not going to find a legal way of doing this because the license for OS X states that is must be run on Apple hardware.  There are also several safeguards in OS X which check to ensure it's running on legit apple hardware.

Comment: @Jesse - Then why is OS X Server Virtualized on Parallels? I know you can *only* virtualize OS X Server, but I am not sire if the host can be anything besides a mac.

Comment: The EULA says that OS X Server can only be virtualized on another OS X server

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal way of doing this due to the Apple EULA.

I have never seen anyone running OSX server on non Apple hardware, but I would imagine it is similar to OSX itself. The easiest way involves getting a modified source image (usually it has a sort of software based EFI), and using VMWare Workstation with a modified VMX file that emulates extra CPU calls.

If you want to learn more, your best bet is to look at [OSX 86 Project](http://www.osx86project.org/) which is a very good source of news for this sort of thing.

Due to the questionable legality of this, I am not sure that I should really be delving much deeper than what I have already said.

Comment: @Wil - I own a valid OS X Server license that I bought directly from Apple. I virtualize OS X Server on my MacBook now. It would just be nice to do my same daily work on a much faster, more scalable system.

Comment: Is it really illegal, or just a breach of the EULA?

Comment: And that valid license is valid for exactly what it says in the EULA.

Comment: @Nathaniel "Really illegal" is a meaningless phrase.  Do you mean is it against criminal statute?  Probably not.  Is it grounds for civil action?  Most definitely.

Comment: @pheobus Ah, you have a point there. Big companies can afford big lawyers.